# nodejs and java api performance comparison

Tags: java, node.js, performance

I have done a performance test of an REST API which is inserting data into MongoDB and also developed two applications using Java and Nodejs Express.

For testing, I have used JMeter which is invoking API 10 times (10 users) and realised that Java gave me consistent performance but Nodejs didn't.
Sometimes Nodejs app is taking more than 2ms to insert simple records into MongoDB.

As I have heard that Nodejs is faster for IO applications but did not find it.

Can someone tell me why I am not getting that performance or is my understanding or result I got is correct?
note: I am Java expert, learning Nodejs.

UPDATE : 
I have created rest api which will insert records in mongodb and I am using mongoose to insert it . below is my code -

```
router.post("/", (req, res, next) => {
    const order = new Order({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        email: req.body.name,
        uid: req.body.uid,
    });
    console.log(order);
    order.save()
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            res.status(201).json({
                message: "Order is successfully added",
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: Have you run a profiler against each? There are a ton of reasons that performance could be different across your implementations in java vs. nodejs.

Yourkit is a great way to understand the performance of your java code, although there are many other tools that will do the same thing: https://www.yourkit.com/
I'm not too familiar with profilers for express but I'm sure you could find a good one. 

If you can post info from each profiler, we can help you understand the performance difference in a scientific way

Comment: can you share the psuedo code that you are trying, there could be different reasons contributing to performance difference

Comment: NodeJS is not really faster than Java. Java may have longer start time, warm up time, but the speed is very comparable (mainly as both platforms can use JIT). If the application is I/O bound (as in your case), then I'd expect the performance will be more dependend on the backend response times.